# How to get local notification everyday at specific time in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to get local notification everyday at 10:00 AM .
my code is:

```
var pushTime = moment().add(0, 'days').hours(10).minutes(0).seconds(0);

    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: 1,
        text: 'Tracking Enabled ',
        trigger: { at: pushTime.toDate() },
        every: 'day'
    });
```

Comment: what is the question then?

Comment: notification is not come at 10 AM.

Comment: Does it come at all?

Comment: If i remove every: 'day' field then notification is come..

Comment: if you remove `every: day`, does the notification pops up once only ?

Comment: Notification is never come with every: 'day' field..

Comment: If i remove then notification is comes once

Comment: I never used `ionic-framework` before but try to replace day with other values like week, year and see what happens

Comment: and wait, if removing `every:day` triggers the notification, why not just keep it that way and add another method which may call this notification method everyday ?

Comment: ok but i have to push notification every day at 10 AM..although i am trying week instead of day

Comment: Just keep the code as it is but remove `every:day`, now create another method to call the method every day..

Comment: And one more.. if notification is come without every field then notification does not clear by swipe on it in tray

Comment: Why it happened ?

Comment: I am not sure, as I said, I never used `ionic-framework`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use trigger as below:

```
trigger: {
   firstAt: pushTime.toDate(),
   every: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.DAY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let notifications = []
let template = {
  data: "value",
  id: 1,
  title: "daily alarm",
  text: 'Code something epic today!',
  launch: true,
  foreground: true,
  trigger: { every: { hour: 10, minute: 0 } },
}
notifications.push(template)
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule(notifications);
```