# Ionic3 LocalNotification every day specifi hour

Tags: triggers, ionic3, localnotification

I've just look at the [docs](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) but the code i've tried work only once.

```
//this is my code
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
  id: 1,
  title: 'Attention',
  text: 'Exmaple',
  data: { mydata: 'My hidden message this is' },
  actions: [
    { id: 'yes', title: 'Yes' },
    { id: 'no', title: 'No' }
  ],

  trigger: { every: { hour: 11, minute: 0 } }//work only once
});
```

I've tried also this ( work only once )

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    title: 'Design team meeting',
    trigger: { in: 1, unit: 'hour' }
});
```

**I want a notification every day at specific hour**

Related to this question:

- [How to get local notification everyday at specific time in ionic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227613/how-to-get-local-notification-everyday-at-specific-time-in-ionic)
- [Send Ionic 3 Local Notification Every day specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860955/send-ionic-3-local-notification-every-day-specific-time)

thanks to all

Comment: anyone know how to solve?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: no, i don't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me, using version **0.9.0-beta.3** like said on this [link](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/1335), I hope I can help you.

```
let dailyNotification = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Time to report',
  text: 'Send your report',
  trigger: { every: { hour: 20, minute: 0} }
};

this.localNotifications.schedule(dailyNotification);
```